# "How to add a textfield on a canvas in android using java?"

Tags: java, android, game-development

I'm struggling to search a method of adding an `editableText` on canvas using java in android, Is there anyone who can give me a hint for creating something like the [image below?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrEq4.png)

[image]

Comment: read `EditText` documentation, and no, you cannot add it "on canvas"

Comment: if its not an EditText, is there any other way I can implement this type of editable textfield?

Comment: sure: write it by yourself, but actually, does it pay off? you have out-of-rhe=box component, so simply use it